# How to backup bugzilla

Tags: linux, backup, debian, bugzilla

The server is bit old running on Debian sarge 3.1.  What are the important things to backup while making a backup of bugzilla? Please guide me how to process with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to specify which version of Bugzilla you are using.

Also, if it's Bugzilla from the Debian package, that might be a bit different - they change it rather a lot, and as a result the core Bugzilla team doesn't support it. The following refers to the upstream package.

You need a dump of the database (`mysqldump` will do that; probably best done when Bugzilla is taken down - use the `shutdownhtml` Bugzilla parameter). You also need a copy of the Bugzilla directory itself on the webserver, as various configuration files and some charting data is stored there. Definitely the files `localconfig` and `data/params`, but probably best just to back up the whole thing. Disk space is cheap, tape space even more so.

Comment: Hi, I am using bugzilla 2.16.7-7sarge1, can upgrade it on same machine or do we need to upgrade debian sarge?